# Why performSelector:withObject:afterDelay can't work well in Unity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

In Unity 4.0.0 default setting.
  I create a UIView and add it to unity window.

In my code I call the function below:

```
   [self performSelector:@selector(hideDelayed:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:animated] afterDelay:delay];
```

I want to perform selector hidelayed: after some seconds. But sometimes the hidelayed: can't be performed. The performSelector:withObject:afterDelay was perform in main therad. and no other place perform cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget.

Does any can give me some tip about this?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.